# Cloud Functions(W/Firestore) Realtime Updates?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, ionic4

This is an nasty problem, I have an Cloud Function that brings all the data in some collection (users), called via app (app calls), then I fetch all the users html, by using the *ngFor.
The problem comes when I delete, create or update some data in this collection, it never updates accordingly, needing me to reload the page.
Is there a possibility of turning this function in a realtime function?

Function exported:

```
  exports.listarAllUsuarios = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
      if(context.auth.token.admin !== true) {
          return {
              error: "Você não possui acesso a essa função"
          };
      }
      return listAllUsers();
  });

    function listAllUsers() {
        let a:string [] = [];
        return db.collection('usuario').get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
          snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            a.push(doc.data());
          });
          return a;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          return error.message;
        });
      }
```

Application .ts

```
  export class ListUserPage implements OnInit {

    listarUser = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('listarAllUsuarios');

    usuario:string[]=[];

    constructor(
    private toast: ToastService,
    ) {


    }

    ionViewWillEnter() {

      this.usuario = [];

      this.listarUser().then(result => {
          return result.data;
      }).then(result => {
        result.map(dados => {
          this.usuario.push(dados);
        });
      }).catch(error => {
        this.toast.errorToast('Erro ao carregar lista de usuários', error)
      });
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }

    detalhesUsuario(usuario) {
      console.log(usuario)
    }
```

Html

```
    <ion-item *ngFor="let usuario of this.usuario">
      <ion-label (click)="detalhesUsuario(usuario)">
        <h1>UID: {{usuario.uid}}</h1>
        <h2>Nome: {{usuario.nomeCompleto}}</h2>
        <h2>E-Mail: {{usuario.email}}</h2>
        <h2>Acesso: {{usuario.role}}</h2>
      </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
```

Comment: I though of returning some path instead of the collection, then using the AngularFire2 to return the data, might try it now...

Comment: Are you using angularfire2?

Comment: Only in the Ionic APP, I am not using it in the admin firestore/functions sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Cloud Function doesn't implement a realtime listener. You're using `get()`, which reads the data once, and then stop listening for it.

In general Cloud Functions are not a good fit for keeping listeners alive, as they can't live longer than 9 minutes.

If you want to keep a communication channel open, consider these alternatives:

1. Implement the listener on a platform that *does* allow long-time listeners, such as Google App Engine, GKE, or pretty much any provider of VM or container instances.
2. Have your client listen directly to Cloud Firestore. This is by far the most effective way to get realtime updates, as you won't have to build your own infrastructure. In fact, most of the code from your Cloud Function should probably be inside your client app, and not on a server.

Comment: I want to make it secure, this is the entire thing about me using CFunctions.
In the 2 option, you mean update it directly in the app?? How would i make it safe besides front end?
I though of doing the cloud function to check, then retrieve the path of the collection, so I could use the valueChanges or snapshot

Comment: Security: see https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/ and https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview

Comment: So i shouldn't be using cloud functions to secure my app/validate data? I already set up some rules aswell in the firestore...

Comment: I'm not saying that you shouldn't use them, as that is up to you. But if you're not accessing Firestore directly from the client, you're definitely losing some of its value - for example its realtime capabilities. It is possible to secure all access to the data through rules. But it's also common to handle read-access through rules, and let all writes go through Cloud Functions since it's a more familiar 'security model' for most devs.